# How do I show a friendly date in a view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a view from my calendar with Start Time and End Time.  As an example it displays as 9/14/2016 9:00 : AM

How do I display just the date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a calculated column with a formula as

> =Text([end time],'MM/DD/YYYY')

[image]

For more on this check this [link](https://wordimpress.com/sharepoint-calendars-remove-the-time-for-calendar-items/)

Comment: For some reason if I use the calculated column as you detailed above my date is 1 day earlier than expected.  As an example  I have a Start Time of 09/01/2016 12:00:00 AM but the calculated column displays 08/31/2016 ?  Any ideas ?  This behavior is found for all my rows.

Comment: Actually this link shows why it is 1 day off...http://weblogs.asp.net/zekemouseover/start-time-amp-calculated-column-wonkiness-in-a-sharepoint-event-calendar

Answer (score 4):

No need to create another calculated column. Just check **Date Only** when you create new column or from your column settings (**Edit Column**).

[image]